# SQLite: query for all unique elements from multiple columns and multiple tables

Tags: sqlite

I got an SQLite table similar to this one:

[image]

I'd like to perform a query that returns all unique user IDs in this table (i.e. all unique values over columns `first_user_id`, `second_user_id` and `third_user_id`). In the example above this query would return `1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7`.

I need this query to be efficient.

The second part of the question concerns the same functionality, but achieved over multiple columns from multiple tables. For example if I also have the following table:

[image]

I would like to know all unique values over columns `first_user_id`, `second_user_id`, `third_user_id`, `first_owner_id`, `second_owner_id`. For the two tables above this query would return `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is the following:

```
SELECT first_user_id AS user_id FROM Participants
UNION
SELECT second_user_id AS user_id FROM Participants
UNION
SELECT third_user_id AS user_id FROM Participants
```

and continue in this way with all the other columns from the other tables.

Comment: Oh thank you, this works (at least for a single table)! I tried to use `||` operator, but it turned to fulfill different functionality. What about the efficiency of this query? I'm asking because you called it "simple", but I'd rather go for "efficient" )

Comment: For efficiency you should try to put an index on all the columns of all the tables, if insertions are not too frequent. Another possibility could be changing the design of the table, depending on the problem domain.

Comment: Indexes to not speed up the computation of the UNIONs.

Comment: @CL. I don't understand your comment. Could you explain what you meant by "Indexes to not speed up the computation of the UNIONs"? Maybe it is something trivial, but I'm really a newb in SQL....

Comment: UNION always puts all the rows into a temporary table (and the individual subqueries must scan their entire table and do not use indexes either).